# Using different layouts in GUIs

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, grid-layout

This is what my program should look like and I'm a bit confused on where I should use different layouts.

I have a Window class which calls the Panel class and the Panel class calls the InputPanel and DisplayPanel classes. My InputPanel class calls my DetailsPanel, CrimePanel and ButtonPanel classes so they make up what is seen under the Input tab. I was told to use a BorderLayout for the whole window, and that the DetailsPanel (left panel) and CrimePanel should be GridLayout.

Does this mean I should:

1. Put the BorderLayout code in Panel and the GridLayout code in CrimePanel and DetailsPanel or
2. Put the BorderLayout code in Window and the GridLayout code in Panel?

[alt text http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/6422/93381955.jpg](http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/6422/93381955.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, your description is a little bit confusing (or I'm still too tired today or didn't have enough caffeine yet). Your notion of "calling" panel classes from others is also a little weird.

But as far as I can see it, your first option is the correct one.

In general you just nest the objects at runtime, so it might look a little like the following:

```
InputPanel (has BorderLayout)
+--DetailsPanel (put in BorderLayout.WEST; has GridLayout)
|  +--nameLabel
|  +--nameTextField
|  +--...
+--CrimePanel (put in BorderLayout.NORTH; has GridLayout)
|  +--murderRadioButton
|  +--arsonRadioButton
|  +--...
+--ButtonPanel (put in BorderLayout.CENTER; has GridLayout)
   +--button
```

You usually do this in the constructor of the appropriate class:

```
public class InputPanel {
    public InputPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(new DetailsPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(new CrimePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(new ButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public class DetailsPanel {

    JLabel nameLabel;
    JTextField nameField;
    // ...

    public DetailsPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));

        nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        nameField = new JTextField();
        // ...

        this.add(nameLabel);
        this.add(nameField);
        // ...
    }
}

...
```

However, I see a small problem here: Since `GridLayout` doesn't allow components to span multiple columns you may need to nest other panels in the `DetailsPanel` on the left as well. You can get away with a single `GridBagLayout` which has the needed capabilities, or you nest other panels there:

```
DetailsPanel (has BorderLayout)
+--panel1 (has GridLayout with 2 rows, 1 column; put in BorderLayout.NORTH)
|  +--nameLabel
|  +--nameField
+--panel2 (has GridLayout with 3 rows, 2 columns; put in BorderLayout.CENTER)
   +--dayField
   +--dayLabel
   +--monthField
   +--...
```

Comment: The centred name label and text field vs side-by-side elements in the rest of West will need some subordinate layout, though.  Either GridBag the whole of West or give it a BorderLayout, with the name bits in one panel in North and the rest in another in Center, with a Grid layout on each sub-panel.

Comment: Already edited :) Noticed that when trying to create the class stubs.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, option 1 should work. Give the Input `JPanel` a `BorderLayout`, with the Details, Crime and Button `JPanel`s (at the west, north and south, respectively) having `GridLayout`s.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to put a JTabbedPane into the Window to contain your two tabs (input and display), each consisting of a JPanel.

The input panel could be subdivided using a BorderLayout as Joannes describes; another alternative is the [GroupLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) introduced in Java 6, which is very powerful, but hard to wrap your mind around. It could be used to layout the entire tab in one panel.